# change a form element by ID with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, customization

The problem:

Working within a Saas environment that processes a form in a way that needs to be altered. It's software-as-a-service so unique changes system wide are not an option.

Attempted Solution:

Attempting to use Javascript which the system is adding to the header area of the page to change the value of a form ID so when the form is submitted it contains the altered value.

The Code:
HTML

```
                <div class="form-group " data-field="how_to_apply">
            <label class="form-label">How to Apply </label>


<div id="application-settings" class="form--move-left clearfix row">
    <div class="form-group form-group__half">
        <input id="via-email" name="ha" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="displayInput(false, 'how_to_apply_1');" type="radio" />
        <label for="via-email" class="form-label">
            By Email<br/>
        </label>
        <input value="systemapplied@emailaddress.com" class="form-control"  name="how_to_apply"  id="how_to_apply_1" type="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group__half">
        <input id="via-site" name="ha" value="2"  onclick="displayInput(false, 'how_to_apply_2');" type="radio" />
        <label for="via-site" class="form-label">
            By URL
        </label>
        <input value="" class="form-control" name="how_to_apply" id="how_to_apply_2" disabled="disabled" type="url" required placeholder="e.g. http://www.yourwebsite.com"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Attempting to change the email address assigned to how_to_apply_1 ID

Javascript Used

```
  document.getElementById("how_to_apply_1").value = "new@emailaddress.com";
```

It is important to add that this works as expected in a CodePen area but does not on the live site so my assumption is that there is something over writing this someplace I am not seeing, or I need to use something else to force the change, I don't know. Any suggestions or help would be GREATLY appreciated

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to wait until the dom is ready. You can either use the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or simply reference your JS right before the closing `body` tag in your `HTML` document.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your script when the DOM is ready. You can wrap your script in DOMContentLoaded event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("how_to_apply_1").value = "new@emailaddress.com";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help